# 'gem install atomic' can't find DevKit even though it's right there in the path, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devkit

Here are some commands from my Windows 7 command prompt that show the problem. As you can see, I added everything I could think of to my path, trying to solve the problem. Same DevKit had worked for me before with the same Ruby installation, so I think I installed it right.

```
E:\ruby\bookmarks3Copy>gem install atomic -v '1.1.9'
ERROR:  Error installing atomic:
        The 'atomic' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

E:\ruby\bookmarks3Copy>path
PATH=f:\ruby\DevKit;f:\ruby\DevKit\bin;[snip];f:\ruby\DevKit\bin;f:\programs\git\bin;"F:\Program Files (x86)\KDiff3"

E:\ruby\bookmarks3Copy>where ruby
f:\ruby\Ruby200-x64\bin\ruby.exe

E:\ruby\bookmarks3Copy>gem list atomic

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

atomic (1.1.14)

E:\ruby\bookmarks3Copy>bundle list atomic
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
f:/ruby/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can share you my solution here,hope it may works

**pik list**

```
It should show you

187: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32] 192: ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32] 193: ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10) [i386-mingw32]
    200: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32] If its not pointing to ruby version 200 then
```

**pik use 200**

**ruby dk.rb install** It will enhance DevKit to your installed Rubies

Finally **gem install rails**

This will install latest rails version 4 for Ruby 2.0